# Data arrived event

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am using Extjs 4.1. I need to identify event on grid when data renderred and arrived.

I checked ''afterrender' event. But it fires to early

```
   grid.on('afterrender', function () {
        alert(333);
    });
```

Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct grid rendered event would fire after grid was rendered not after the data is displayed. What about subscribing to the store `load` event?

```
store.on('load', function() {
...
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply need to know when the grid has first loaded data, use the `Ext.grid.Panel` [**viewready**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-viewready) event, it fires when the data has been loaded in and the grid rows have been rendered.

**Example:**

```
this.control({

    'mygridpanel': {

        // select the first record
        viewready: function(grid) {
            var store = grid.getStore(),
                view = grid.getView(),
                selModel = grid.getSelectionModel();
            if (store.getAt(0)) {
                view.focus();
                selModel.select(0);
            }
        },
    },
});
```

This example is configured in the `init` function of a controller using the MVC pattern, I'm not sure if you are using MVC pattern? The snippet in your comment should work fine either way though.

Also this event passes the `Ext.grid.Panel` object that fired it as the first argument, as you can see from the example above, you can use that to get a reference to your grid and perform whatever logic you need to do on it in your handler.

Comment: grid.on('viewready', function () {
        alert(333);
    });  Will work ?

Comment: @GregoryNozik I added the example, I've been using MVC pattern so all my event handlers are in my controller - that's what my example above is configured for. The snippet you posted in the comment above should work fine however if you don't want to use MVC pattern.